# iPhone bluetooth client to localhost voiceover

Tags: ios, bluetooth, voiceover, ios-bluetooth, braille

**A little background for my question**: Braille keyboards connect to apple voiceover via bluetooth.  They receive a text stream from voiceover wherever the user takes actions on the device.  The keyboard is able to send commands to the iPhone which map to gestures, etc, so they can control the device via the braille keyboard.

I'm interested in writing an iPhone app which can emulate a braille keyboard. This would allow me to capture the voiceover data stream and to send the same commands/gestures that the braille keyboard can send.

**My Question:** Is it possible for an iPhone app make a bluetooth client connection to voiceover on localhost to emulate a braille keyboard?  I'm happy with test flight for now.  Example code or references appreciated.